# How to Animate a Control Using the Unloaded Event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, routed-events

I hate to make another question so soon, but I can't seem to get this to work quite right.

I have a `UserControl` with a `StoryBoard` set to run when the `Unloaded RoutedEvent` occurs. However, I also have the code so that it will remove the the `UserControl` from its containing `StackPanel` when a button is clicked. What I would like to see happen is when that delete button is clicked, the `StoryBoard` runs, *then* the `UserControl` is removed from the `StackPanel`.

There's a lot of code already, so I'm not sure what to place. Let me know what code you want me to place for you to help me.

All I have is a `RoutedEvent` in the `UserControl` that raises the delete (or unload) event:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent deleteEvent = 
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("delete", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(TimeEntry));

    private void raiseDeleteEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newDeleteEvent = new RoutedEventArgs(deleteEvent,this);
        RaiseEvent(newDeleteEvent);
    }

    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        raiseDeleteEvent();
    }
```

then, two methods in the main window that registers to the event being thrown:

```
    private void entryAdder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentSession.addEntry(DateTime.Now);
        scrollStack.Children.Add(currentSession.currentTimeEntry);
        currentSession.currentTimeEntry.delete += currentTimeEntry_delete;
    }

    void currentTimeEntry_delete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scrollStack.Children.Remove(sender as TimeEntry);
    }
```

and finally, the `UserControl`, with its `StoryBoard`s:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="Ondelete">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is using a timer to delay the removal but I don't know if this is the best one

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve my problem. I decided not to use the `Unloaded` event to make the animation, but instead procedurally code the animation, then have the `UserControl` subscribe to the `Completed` event of that `DoubleAnimation`, and finally trigger its own delete event, which would make anything subscribed to *that* event occur (i.e. the removal from the visual  `StackPanel` and list of `UserControl` objects). This would allow the animation to run, and then, when it is finished, raise the deletion event.

Here's the mess of code for that. It's all pretty much summed up in these method calls. They're located within the `UserControl`:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent deleteEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("delete", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(TimeEntry));

 private TransformGroup animatedTransform;
 private ScaleTransform animatedScale;

 private DoubleAnimation deleteDoubleAnimation;

 public UserControl()//the constructor
 {
     timeIn = DateTime.Now;
     timeSpent = timeOut - timeIn;
     this.InitializeComponent();
     setUpRenderTransform();
     setUpAnimationVariables();
     deleteDoubleAnimation.Completed += deleteDoubleAnimation_Completed;
 }

private void setUpRenderTransform()
{
    animatedTransform = new TransformGroup();
    animatedScale = new ScaleTransform();
    animatedTransform.Children.Add(animatedScale);

    this.RenderTransform = animatedTransform;

}

private void setUpAnimationVariables()
{
    deleteDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    deleteDoubleAnimation.To = 0;
    deleteDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:.25"));
}

private void raiseDeleteEvent()
{
    RoutedEventArgs newDeleteEvent = new RoutedEventArgs(deleteEvent, this);
    RaiseEvent(newDeleteEvent);
}

private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    deleteAnimation();
}

void deleteDoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    raiseDeleteEvent();
}

private void deleteAnimation()
{
    animatedScale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, deleteDoubleAnimation);
    animatedScale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, deleteDoubleAnimation);
}
```